# Using jQuery, how can I get an image to open full screen to the browser's height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, css

I'd like to create a jQuery function that accepts an image url, and when executed, displays the image full screen matching the height and width of the current page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> .css({height:'100%',width:'100%',
>   position:'fixed', top:0, left:0});

You can use animation too.

> .animate({height:'100%',width:'100%', position:'absolute', top:0, left:0});

Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for reference.

Comment: IE6 doesn't support `fixed` positioning. `absolute` might be enough, though.

Comment: hi mendy, i am new to JQuery and i also need to implement same functionality... can you please provide syntax to use animation??

Comment: Hi -- When I do this, I still see the scroll bars from the page that is underneath the image.  How can I remove them, and then re-apply them when the image come back ?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use Overflow:'hidden' in the body tag.

Comment: Thanks!  Any way to get the height/width to stay in proportion?  Right now it's stretching the image.

Answer (score 0):

just for your information: If your webpage is running under an iframe then you have to set ***mozallowfullscreen*** and ***webkitallowfullscreen***. These attributes allows contents to be open in fullscreen.

```
<iframe src="testA.html" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```